# How to get a smooth sloping curved wall?

Tags: modeling, screw-modifier

I've created this curved wall using the spin tool, however I need to make it slope down giving me equal space above the treads.

I tried using the screw modifier on a seperate test wall, but could not get any settings that worked out.

Here is the [3D](https://skfb.ly/oFPLW) in its current state, but the wall doesn't have smooth descent

Many thanks.

[image: stair wall]

[image]

Comment: is the knife tool a possibility for you like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZieQ.png

Comment: @Chris Perfect that is exactly the shape I am after. However, how would I then cut around the whole shape, as 'occlude geometry' off leaves it with a slant?

Answer (score 1):

Providing the slope is constant you could just create it with a simple box and apply a boolean modiffier
[image]

[image]

[image]

Personally I'd model it the other way round and start with the slope itself. I don't really think the screw modifier is the best way to go about this. You could recreate the slope as a bezier curve by snapping points to vertices of your stairs.

[image]

Then you could convert it to mesh (Object -> covert -> mesh).

[image]

Extrude it along z-axis, select the bottom edges and scale them to 0 along z axis.

[image]

And finally give it thickness either by extruding along normals, or by using the solidify modifier

[image]

This method will also work for changing slope which is probably what you are after.